# Ubuntu Server 18.04 - ExpressVPN at boot

Tags: boot, vpn, cron, debian, init.d

What would be the correct way to start the Express vpn client at boot detailed [here](https://www.expressvpn.com/support/vpn-setup/app-for-linux/#command-line)

Specifically;

```
In the terminal, run the following command:

expressvpn connect
```

I would want this to run at boot unattended. Research indicates there are many methods of starting things at boot from crontab to init.d to creating a service, etc.

I am after the "correct" way to achieve the running this at boot within the 18.04 ecosystem.

Answer (score 1):

Dont know if this is what your looking for, i just created a text file, right clicked -properties - permissions tab and selected allow executing file as a program, saved then pointed start up programs to the file.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
expressvpn connect smart
```

you can leave the smart off or replace with preferred server, worked for me